# How to specify database name in Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

```
public Constructor(string DBName)
{
   DB = DBName;
}
[Database(Name = DB)]
public class Database5 : DataContext
{
    …
}
```

Is there a way that I can use value in DB variable to give DB name like code snippet above without give an error?

The reason why I want to this because my project need to generate a new database everyday(Database have the same table but different name).

Comment: Do you mean to create a new database depending upon the *databasename* that you pass periodically (daily)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you need to create a new database depending up on a name, daily. You could simply use a constructor overload for your app's db context like this:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{

    public AppDbContext(string databaseNameOrConnectionString)
        : base(databaseNameOrConnectionString)
    {
        // This line creates a new database if it does not exist on the database server. 
        // Just ensure that you pass a new name periodically to get a new database.
        Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AppDbContext>());
    }
// other overloads of the db context, if needed
}
```

And then you could use the constructor like this:

```
var dbContext = new AppDbContext("Database5");
```

You will have to come up with a mechanism to periodically change the database name and use it while creating the `AppDbContext`